# I have a list of URL's and I want to know to which html div each URL belongs in a HTML page

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a list of URL's and I want to know to which html div each URL belongs in a HTML page
I have to do it using java

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details before anyone can even begin to answer your question.

Comment: Could you include what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: I have  a webpage, I need to get all the urls from the page. I am able to do that. But I also want to know the url which I am taking belongs to which div

Comment: use parsers like jsoup or apache html parser to parse the html and use comparision to find out the div.

Comment: Yes, I'm using jsoup to get the elements

Comment: is there a way I can know the div name using jsoup?

Comment: For example:

<div class="header" data-header-type="desktop">
 <style>.gh-hide-if-nocss{display:none;}.gh-ar-hdn{color:#fff}</style>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/32q2wauokmyjletm4byq40w5s2i.css?proc=DU:N"></link><![endif]--> </div>

I want something like this as a output

class="header" 
URL http://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/32q2wauokmyjletm4byq40w5s2i.css

I'm doing something like this:
Elements urls = doc.select("a[href]");
for(Element url: urls){
System.out.println(url.id());
}

But this is giving me the id of the link (a)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question needs improvement. For a start, please add the info to your question and not the comment section. Give the code your are using, what you get and what you expect. Then I am sure you get meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the divs and loop through the div's to get the links using jsoup.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();
Elements divs = doc.select("div");

for (Element div : divs) {
        String linkHref = div.attr("name"); 
    Elements links = div.select("a[href]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but here is my guess: You try to get the href attribute text of an anchor element. If this is so, you can simply access it like this whithin your loop:

```
String hrefStr = url.attr("href");
```